# Query For Linq Count

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

Can anyone translate this query into Linq? This query counts the number of ATTENDANCE of an Employee.

```
select 
    count(attandance.empid),
    employee2.empname 
from 
    employee2
inner join 
    attandance 
    on employee2.empid=attandance.empid
group by 
    employee2.empname
```

Comment: Here is most of the examples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: What did you try? If you don't know LinQ, learn it or hire someone who can do this for you. This site is for getting help *after trying yourself*.

Comment: Please review the code what I have meant. I have given a caption for that. One more thing do you have any idea about who has written the above query??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var attendance = (from e in db.employee2 // db would be your datacontext
                  select new 
                  {
                     empName = e.empname,
                     attendanceCount = (from a in db.attandance
                                        where a.empid == e.empid).Count()
                  });
```

If you don't want to use a datacontext, you can try the above linq in [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) by connecting to a data source.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the same results as your sql. If you are using linq to sql or EF, just replace the two List with your datasources.

```
        List<Employee2> employee2 = new List<Employee2>
        {
            new Employee2 { EmpId = 1, EmpName = "Bob" },
            new Employee2 { EmpId = 2, EmpName = "Sam" },
            new Employee2 { EmpId = 3, EmpName = "Jim" },
        };

        List<Attendance> attandance = new List<Attendance>
        {
            new Attendance { EmpId = 1 },
            new Attendance { EmpId = 2 },
            new Attendance { EmpId = 2 },
            new Attendance { EmpId = 3 },
            new Attendance { EmpId = 3 },
            new Attendance { EmpId = 3 },
        };

        var r = from emp in employee2
                join att in attandance on emp.EmpId equals att.EmpId
                group emp by emp.EmpName into g
                select new { EmpName = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```